# Purged nvidia drivers, now I have no ethernet, no wireless and no bluetooth device

Tags: drivers

So the title kind of says it all. I tried installing cuda, as usual, cuda install broke something (I somehow alwqys either end up not being able to load X or not being able to put the laptop to sleep), so as usual I purged anything nvidia.

After reboot now I'm absolutely unable to connect to the internet (no ethernet driver, no wireless driver) and the graphics are also very bad resolution so no graphics card either I guess. These obviously all worked fine before so I'm absolutely baffled how they could have broken due to an nvidia purge.

As I have never found myself in this situation I have no idea how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ah, something's messed up with the kernel, an older one worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking about deleting, but considering how I didn't manage to find an answer:

What I needed to due is to reboot and get into the grub menu (which is pressing escape if you have uefi, but that might end you up in the grub shell, then you need to type `normal`) and choose an older kernel and then update all packages (this included a new kernel, so it might not have had to do with the nvidia purging per se).